# failed of open stream error for file_put_contents

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions, centos7

I am trying to write some text content to a file in php.

I am using the file_put_contents for this.

my code looks like this

```
<?php

file_put_contents('/var/www/html/test.txt', 'this is my content');
```

but this keeps returning errors, no matter what I do. It says file_put_contents centos failed to open stream

the folders exists, and I just tried giving 777 permissions to the html folder. but nothing works.

strangely if I change the path to the temp dir

```
<?php

file_put_contents('/tmp/test.txt', 'this is my content');
```

then it writes with no errors.

I am using centos 7, and a GUI version.

any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does that file(`/var/www/html/test.txt`) exists? and is writable?

Comment: the whole html folder has 777 permissions and yes that file exists. but file_put_contents should create the file it is not there isnt it ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?